# Resize images when resize window without leaving gaps between the images

Tags: css, autoresize

I'm trying to build a website with 4 columns of images spanning across the whole page. When users re-size the browser, i want those images to re-size as well, proportionality of course. My problem is, i could get those images to re-size properly if the window is smaller than the max width size for the images. However, if the browser is larger, there are big gaps in between the column. I want the images to stack right against each other with no gap in between. Any idea? My alternative solution is if the browser is larger, i want the column of images, still stack right against each other, to be place in the middle of the page. I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Codes are below.

HTML:

```
<body background="Images/BG_paper_008_dark.jpg">
<div id="header">
<div id="logo"><img src="Images/DTP_logo_final_white.gif" /></div>
<div id="menu">Wedding | Engagement | Family/Portrait | Products | Action | The world through my eyes </div>
</div>

<div id="midbody">
<div id="mainImg1"><img src="Images/FrontPage_L1_Image1.jpg" alt="Horse racing"/>
                   <img src="Images/FrontPage_L1_Image2.jpg" alt="Horse racing"/></div>
<div id="mainImg2"><img src="Images/FrontPage_L1_Image3.jpg" alt="Horse racing"/>
<img src="Images/FrontPage_L1_Image4.jpg" alt="Horse racing"/> </div>
<div id="mainImg3"><img src="Images/FrontPage_L1_Image5.jpg" alt="Horse racing"/>
<img src="Images/FrontPage_L1_Image6.jpg" alt="Horse racing"/></div>
<div id="mainImg4"><img src="Images/FrontPage_L1_Image7.jpg" alt="Horse racing"/>
<img src="Images/FrontPage_L1_Image8.jpg" alt="Horse racing"/></div>  
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#midbody {
clear: both;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

#mainImg1 {
width: 25%;
clear: left;
float: left;
text-align: center;

}
#mainImg2 {
width: 25%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
}
#mainImg3 {
width: 25%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
}
#mainImg4 {
width: 25%;
clear: right;
float: left;
text-align: center;
}

img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you can't set the img class to width:100% instead of using a max width?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't want the images to scale larger than their 'intrinsic' widths?

If you know the maximum widths of the images you could add a containing DIV within "midbody" which is 100% wide(inherited from midbody) but, has a max-width of the total max-width of the images within it:
     ...

If you don't know the total maximum width of the images than I think you will have to use javascript or PHP or something like that because you won't be able to get a DIV to inherit a max-width.